# How to remove links from top.liknks when loggin in / out in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: authentication, logout, magento-1.6

I've had a good search around and found the `customer_logged_in` and `customer_logged_out` tags but I can't get them to work properly, this I'm sure is down to my misunderstanding of them.

My goal is to hide the log in, account and checkout links from the block `top.links` when the user is *not* logged in and show them when the user *is* logged in.

I have placed the following at the end of my `local.xml` file to try and remove the log in link:

```
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

</default>
```

But it does not work. Can someone please explain why this does not work? It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the reason, first off they are top level tags and shouldn't be put in the default tag and secondly it just wasn't working in the local.xml so I placed the code at the top of the customer.xml and it works a treat. Note: I removed the xml which added links to the top.links as well as this seems to interfere with it.

Working xml:

```
<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged in
-->

    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout"><label>My Cart</label><url helper="checkout/cart/getCartUrl"/><title>My Cart</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>9</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Sign up</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register </title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/url/getCheckoutUrl"/></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/cart/getCartUrl"/></action>         
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

Answer (score 7):

Removing links in local.xml works in my case. Here is the code:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: Also works for me, but only with the tags as you posted them, not the `<default>` one.

Comment: works, make sure you include it by `<url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>`
and not by `<url>customer/account/login/</url>`