# Magento : How to hide a link on login

Tags: magento-1.6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove links from top.liknks when loggin in / out in Magento 1.6.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754281/how-to-remove-links-from-top-liknks-when-loggin-in-out-in-magento-1-6-2)

When the user logs in, I want the register link to be hidden. Can any one guide me on this? I am new to it.

Only thing which comes to mind is `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();`, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the layout files to solve this using the `<customer_logged_in>` tags.

Have a look in your customer.xml and you would normally have:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="topLinks">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

and an equivalent for `<customer_logged_out>`. This should lead you where you need.

If you really want to do it in the `phtml` file, then look at

```
$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
```